# How to split a variable into 2 variables?

Tags: php

So, I have a text box with a form. Where people can write thing in this specific order:

```
1:2
2:3
3:4
7:8
```

And it will get sended with POST to another `.php file`. There everything will be getted with `$_POST['input']`. But now I want the following thing: That it will get ordered. So from

```
1:2
2:3
3:4
7:8
```

to

```
$arg['1'] = 1;
$arg1['1'] = 2;
$arg['2'] = 2;
$arg1['2'] = 3;
$arg['3'] = 3;
$arg1['3'] = 4;
$arg['4'] = 7;
$arg1['4'] = 8;
```

How can I do this stuff? thanks!

Comment: Is each number seperated by a space? e.g (1:1 2:8: 5:2)

Comment: What decides whether it is `$arg['1']` or `$arg['2']`???

Comment: I don't get your examples? You want to set the key 2 to 4 different values? Why? Why not make an associative array with the key being the first digit and the value being a (list?) of numbers? This seems like an XY problem most than anything.

Comment: Please edit your question to fix arg/arg1['3']  and ['4'] you have them as ['2'].

Comment: @MinistryofChaps each number is seperated with enter.

Comment: @AbraCadaver The ':'. Every line. The text before ':' goes to @arg['1'] and after it goes to @arg1['1']. And that every line.

Comment: @FreeRobloxStuff how is your $_POST['input'] receiving this information then? Is it like `1:2\n2:3\n3:4\n7:8`? If you have an example of how your input comes in then that would help.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is:

1. If there is a space breaking up each number:number, use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to contain each one to an array.
2. Create a foreach loop to deal with each number:number element in the array. You should use the explode function again to seperate the numbers each side of the comma.

   ```
    $input = "1:2 2:3 3:4 7:8";
   //Will put input into an array as array("1:2", "2:3" ...)
    $inputToArray = explode(" ", $input);

    $arg = array();
    $arg1 = array();

    $i = 1;
    foreach ($inputToArray as $element)
        {

        //Will turn element in array from 'number:number' into a new array 
        //(e.g array('1:1') will now be array(1, 1);
        $splitNumbers = explode(":", $element);

        $arg[$i] = $splitNumbers[0];
        $arg1[$i] = $splitNumbers[1];

       // To visibly show that it is working.
       echo "arg['$i'] : " . $arg[$i] . "<br>";
       echo "arg1['$i'] : " . $arg1[$i] . "<br>";

    $i++;
    }
   ```